# Ansible Playbook running for longtime/indefinitely for .exe installation task using psexec module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, winrm, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am new to Ansible and I'm trying to configure windows 2012 R2 from RHEL Centos 7 Node.
I'm able to establish connection between them using Winrm Credssp.
Below is /etc/ansible/group_vars/windows.yml file

```
---
 ansible_user: admin
 ansible_password: XXXXXXX
 ansible_winrm_scheme: https
 ansible_winrm_transport: credssp
 ansible_port: 5986
 ansible_connection: winrm
 ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
 validate_certs: false
```

In /etc/ansible/hosts file I have defined windows FQDN

```
[windows]
xx.xx.xx.xx
```

When I execute win_ping module for testing connection from central Linux node to Windows 2012 R2 server it was successful.

```
[root@centos playbooks]# ansible windows -m win_ping
XX.XX.XX.XX | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

But When I have tried installing sample .exe (VLC) file in local drive using below playbook file, after submitting ansible-playbook playbook.yml command, it is continuously waiting for indefinite time, as It is not completing .exe installation.
Note: PsExec.exe location is updated in PATH env variable for windows.

```
---
  - name: Windows ansible playbook
    hosts: windows
    tasks:
      - name: installing VLC
        win_psexec:
         command: 'E:\\Softwares\\VLC.exe'
         system: yes
```

Below is console output after submitting ansible-playbook command for above playbook.

```
PLAY [Windows ansible playbook] ************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [192.168.2.14]

TASK [installing VLC] **********************************************************
```

Below is the log that is constantly displaying same. Waiting continuously.
/var/log/ansible/log

```
2017-10-27 22:22:32,574 p=4269 u=root |  TASK [installing VLC] **********************************************************
2017-10-27 22:22:32,672 requests_credssp.credssp The credentials that will be used in the auth, DOMAIN: '.', USER: 'admin'
2017-10-27 22:22:32,675 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.2.14
2017-10-27 22:22:32,712 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 401 0
2017-10-27 22:22:32,714 requests_credssp.credssp _start_tls_handshake(): Starting TLS handshake with server
2017-10-27 22:22:32,715 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool Resetting dropped connection: 192.168.2.14
2017-10-27 22:22:32,771 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 401 0
2017-10-27 22:22:32,774 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 401 0
2017-10-27 22:22:32,775 requests_credssp.credssp _start_tls_handshake(): Handshake complete. Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
2017-10-27 22:22:32,775 requests_credssp.credssp _get_authentication_token(): creating NTLM negotiate token and add it to the initial TSRequest
2017-10-27 22:22:32,776 requests_credssp.credssp _get_authentication_token(): NTLM Negotiate Token: TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAMpCI4gEAAQAoAAAAAAAAACkAAAAGAbEdAAAADy4=
2017-10-27 22:22:32,776 requests_credssp.credssp _get_authentication_token(): get NTLM challenge token from the server and add it to the ntlm context
2017-10-27 22:22:32,777 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 401 0
2017-10-27 22:22:32,779 requests_credssp.credssp _get_authentication_token(): NTLM Challenge Token: TlRMTVNTUAACAAAADwAPADgAAAA2goriAQ4M49EAIqMAAAAAAAAAAJgAmABHAAAACgBaKQAAAA9ERVNLVE9QLUVETEFLRzQCAB4ARABFAFMASwBUAE8AUAAtAEUARABMAEEASwBHADQAAQAeAEQARQBTAEsAVABPAFAALQBFAEQATABBAEsARwA0AAQAHgBEAEUAUwBLAFQATwBQAC0ARQBEAEwAQQBLAEcANAADAB4ARABFAFMASwBUAE8AUAAtAEUARABMAEEASwBHADQABwAIAGOmEf9DT9MBAAAAAA==
2017-10-27 22:22:32,779 requests_credssp.credssp _get_authentication_token(): create NTLM authentication token
2017-10-27 22:22:32,782 requests_credssp.credssp _send_auth_response(): Generate the encrypted public key data and add it to the TSRequest
2017-10-27 22:22:32,783 requests_credssp.credssp _send_auth_response(): Send TSRequest structure containing the final auth token and public key info
2017-10-27 22:22:32,783 requests_credssp.credssp _send_auth_response(): Get the public key structure response from the server
2017-10-27 22:22:32,786 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 401 0
2017-10-27 22:22:32,786 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 401 0
2017-10-27 22:22:32,787 requests_credssp.credssp _verify_public_keys(): Get raw public key from the server and decrypt it for verification
2017-10-27 22:22:32,788 requests_credssp.credssp _verify_public_keys(): verification of the server's public key is successful
2017-10-27 22:22:32,788 requests_credssp.credssp _send_encrypted_credentials(): Sending the encrypted credentials to the server
2017-10-27 22:22:32,822 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 200 1636
2017-10-27 22:22:32,832 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 200 847
2017-10-27 22:22:33,116 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 200 753
2017-10-27 22:22:33,889 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 200 998
2017-10-27 22:22:53,934 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 500 1320
2017-10-27 22:23:13,978 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 500 1320
2017-10-27 22:23:34,024 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 500 1320
2017-10-27 22:23:54,069 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 500 1320
2017-10-27 22:24:14,114 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 500 1320
```

above log continues/updates same for every 20 sec. This task .exe installation was never completed.

```
2017-10-27 22:24:14,114 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /wsman HTTP/1.1" 500 1320
```

Please suggest what change/Update I have to do on windows side so that .exe file installation should be completed.

Answer (score 1):

vlc.exe is likely waiting for input, so it will just hang there indefenetely. Same happens if you start "notepad". You need to figure out how to install the software silently so that it returns an exit code.

Not sure why you'd want to use win_psexec instead of win_package to install, but in any case you need to be able to make sure that the process exits and returns.

Answer (score 0):

Silent installation options worked for this. Same PsExec with `/S /VERYSILENT` arguments worked for me.